# Добавление файлов в архив с зашифрованными именами файлов. SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, 7z

При добавлении файлов в архив с зашифрованными именами файлов получаю исключение: *Invalid archive: open/read error! Is it encrypted and a wrong password was provided?
If your archive is an exotic one, it is possible that SevenZipSharp has no signature for its format and thus decided it is TAR by mistake. Message: Can not update the archive: Open() failed.*
Если `EncryptHeaders = false` то всё работает нормально. 
А как добавить если `EncryptHeaders = true`?

```
SevenZipCompressor szc = new SevenZipCompressor();
szc.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip;
szc.ZipEncryptionMethod = ZipEncryptionMethod.Aes256;
//szc.EncryptHeaders = true;

szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", "123", @"C:\Test\123.txt");
szc.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Append;
szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", "123", @"C:\Test\1234.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Существует, как минимум, два варианта решения данной проблемы.

**1. Изменить формат архива.**

Вместо

```
szc.ArchiveFormat = SevenZip.OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip;
```

использовать

```
szc.ArchiveFormat = SevenZip.OutArchiveFormat.Zip;
```

как советуют [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321927/sevenzipsharp-append-an-encrypted-archive).

**2. Добавлять все файлы одновременно передавая полные пути в массиве при создании архива.**

Например:

```
string[] arr = { @"C:\Test\1234.txt", @"C:\Test\1235.txt" };
...
szc.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
szc.CompressFilesEncrypted("test.7z", "123", arr);
```

Однако в этом случае все файлы добавляются сразу и добавить два раза один и тот же файл не получится.

Comment: 1. при `szc.ArchiveFormat = SevenZip.OutArchiveFormat.Zip` имена файлов не шифруются.

Comment: 2. я архивирую сначала группу файлов через `CompressDictionary`, но потом нужно добавлять ещё файлы.